# why the position of elements is changing when the browser zoomed in or out?

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem in my CSS layouts, that when the browser is zoomed all the elements positions are changed, how I can avoid this problem?
I want all the elements to be zoomed in the same scale and stay in their positions, or to control the elements character

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/94mBq/)

here is my css:

```
html
{
    border: groove 8px red;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    text-align: center;
}

.container
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height:75%;
    color: white;
}

.container .input
{
    width: 49%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000099;
    float: left;
}

.container .break
{
    width: 2%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #b8b8b8;
    float: left;
}

.container .output
{
    width: 49%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #b80000;
    float: right;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container > * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.input h3, .output h3
{
    color: white;
}

.input textarea
{
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 70%;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    transform: none;
}

.input input[type="submit"], .input input[type="reset"]  
{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}

.input input[type="submit"]:active, .input input[type="reset"]:active
{
    background: #858585;
    color: #fffccc;
}
```

Comment: The CSS isn't much use without the HTML to go with it. Can you link to a page or make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem you're describing?

Comment: did u refresh after zoom in?

Comment: I faced a similar problem once. For me it worked to leave a bit more free space between divs. For example you have two divs with 49% width and one last div with 2%. This makes a total of 100% which would be logical but for some reason this can be a problem when zooming... I'd try leaving out the 2% div in the middle

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai yes I did

Comment: @oHoodie this suggestion is useless

Comment: @user3194430: Cool maybe there is a medal for leaving useless suggestions

Comment: oHoodie is probably right. There can be little 1px differences in browsers that cause your layout to reach 101% and then things break. I'd probably also try using inline-block rather than float.